# Random image on page load

Tags: image, random

I want to make a website showing random images on each page load, i know there are scripts which can do this,but i have seen a website which does the same without the script, as can be from source of the website
http://onlive95.com/apps/ig/victoria-secret/index.html
After opening source code,if you refresh the source page,the image url changes ,which suggest that its fetching images from web,and i want to do the same but i am not getting what script code is doing that to fetch images.
here is another website which kind of doing the same thing

http://roflhits.us/

Answer (score 0):

If you are correct in saying you don't see it in the page (ie not by Javascript), then it is done serverside by a language like PHP, Python, Java etcetera.
As for an implementation, Stackoverflow is not here to code for you, but to help you coding.

Comment: thank you for replying, i am not asking anybody to code for me ,i would be great if someone can help identify of the kind of script that is running on these website

Comment: if it's not visible, then it probably a back-end script, and hard to figure out without having access to their code